# Why am I forced to use !! in a combination of null checks?

Tags: kotlin

For this piece of code, Kotlin forces me to handle a null-check situation while on the other line it doesn't, despite being the same situation:

```
if (r1 == null && r2 == null)
    throw IllegalArgumentException("All nulls!")
else if (r1 == null)
    return r2!!.reading // <----- I am forced to !! here
else if (r2 == null)
    return r1.reading // <----- The compiler does not complain in this line
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: both r1 and r2 vals?

Comment: Why check for non null values by process of elimination instead of directly checking for non null? e.g. `r2?.reading ?: r1?.reading ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("All nulls!")`

Comment: @mfulton26 the `if` expression in the question is not exhaustive, i.e. it doesn't cover the case when both `r1` and `r2` are not null. So while your suggestion might be useful in some cases, in this case it isn't equivalent.

Comment: After another look the question's example code returns `r1.reading` when both `r1` and `r2` are not null. I think a good, idiomatic way to write this in Kotlin would be `(r1 ?: r2 ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("All nulls!")).reading`.

Comment: @mfulton26 once again, in the question if both `r1` and `r2` are not null, nothing is returned and execution continues.

Comment: Oops. Thank you @Ilya. I see now what you mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Kotlin compiler does not make logical inferences in the way you expect: "I have already checked that r1 == null and r2 == null, so now if I'm only checking for r1 == null, then it must recognize that r2 is not null". It doesn't. You haven't checked r2 in that branch, so it doesn't see that it is not null.

In the second case the situation is simpler: `if (r1 == null) { ... } else { ... }`. It doesn't matter that you have another check inside the `else`; the compiler sees that you're in the `else` branch of an `if (x == null)` check and understands that the value is not null.

There is an [open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10461) for adding this kind of logic, however, it's not on the near term roadmap of the Kotlin team.

Comment: I see. I would only expect those !! in a multi thread context.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, if some application logics are mutually exclusive. I would prefer to use `when {}` to declaratively express full conditions case by case rather than using `if(...) else if(..) else` to compose the logic.

Using `when{}` to specify the full conditions case by case can help developers just focus on particular case which is easier for debugging and later changes.

In contrast, an `if else` conditions forced developers to trace from the top to bottom to get the whole idea of that part logic which is comparatively difficult for others to read and difficult to point out unreachable code.

I had met some complex `if else` codes and I have to build a truth table for understanding the whole part of logic.

Coming back to the question. Smart case works well with `when{}` :)

Implementation 1

```
val someReading = when {
    r1 != null && r2 == null -> r1.reading
    r1 == null && r2 != null -> r2.reading
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("All nulls!")
}
```

Implementation 2

```
val someReading =
        r1?.reading
        ?: r2?.reading
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("All nulls!")
```

Comment: Note that the first implementation throws when both `r1` and `r2` are not null, when it shouldn't. The second one is also not equivalent to the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could slightly restructure your `if` expression, so it would make less checks and have smart-cast applied to `r2`:

```
if (r1 == null) {
    if (r2 == null) throw IllegalArgumentException("All nulls!")
    return r2.reading
} else if (r2 == null) {
    return r1.reading
}
```